# gmplot library. list(map(float values won't work with marker but work with heatmap. why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, coordinates, gmplot

The data is pulled from two columns in Google Sheets with this:

```
latitude = list(map(float, wks.col_values(3)[1:]))
longitude = list(map(float, wks.col_values(4)[1:]))
```

Here's the code behind creating the map:

```
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(33.204345, -71.67478, 14, apikey="")
gmap.heatmap(latitude, longitude)   #this works
gmap.marker(latitude, longitude, color='cornflowerblue')  

gmap.draw("test55.html")
```

The gmap.heatmap works perfectly fine.... However, the gmap.marker won't work at all and yields the following error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

Why won't gmap marker accept my coordinates? :|

Comment: The `marker()` method wants a single coordinate pair, not lists of coordinates.  If you want a marker for each point, you'll need to call it in a loop.

Comment: ugh this again. TypeError: must be real number, not list. Any idea how to do this? I'll add my attempt in an edit above.

Comment: What was that edit supposed to do?  You've just recreated two lists of floats that are identical to the two lists of floats you already had.  What you need to do is something like `gmap.marker(latitude[0], longitude[0])`.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you. Any idea how to get it to loop through every spreadsheet entry? for example: 

gmap.marker(latitude[0], longitude[0], title="test")
gmap.marker(latitude[1], longitude[1], title=elementfromcolumn5)
gmap.marker(latitude[2], longitude[2], title=elementfromcolumn5)

Comment: got it: for x in range(0, 3):
    gmap.marker(latitude[x], longitude[x], title=boxnumber[x])

Edit: If you want to respond to the question with your previous answer, i'll give you credit. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you could loop over `marker()` manually, but an easier option is to just use [`scatter()`](https://github.com/gmplot/gmplot/wiki/GoogleMapPlotter.scatter):

```py
gmap.scatter(latitude, longitude, color='cornflowerblue')
```